# Handling sequential numbering in relative ranges for varying list sizes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am creating a macro that builds a document from several dozen different worksheets.  It pulls lists (which can vary in length) from each of these sheets, and places them in tables on the estimate page.  The items in each table are sequentially numbered.  This sequential numbering starts over again in each table on the estimate sheet.

I have updated this question with more information because the answers have made it clear that I'm using a non-standard way of building tables.  I've included the full macro below, as well as some sample output.

Here's the full macro script for context:

```
'declare global variables
Dim WorkingPercentage As Variant
Dim EstimateDate As Variant
Dim LastRow As Variant
Dim EstLastRow As Variant
Dim NumRows As Integer
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim fillrange As Range
Dim est_sht As Worksheet
Dim answer As Integer
Dim InputPercentage As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim subcat_yn As Variant
Dim subcatprice As Variant

Sub IterateSheets()

'associate worksheet variables with job categories worksheets
Set est_sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Estimate Report")
'declare other variables

Dim WshtNameCrnt As Variant
Dim WshtNames As Variant

'prompt user whether estimate sheets are completely filled out"
answer = MsgBox("Have you completed the estimate for all relevant labor categories?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Populate Estimate")

If answer = vbYes Then

'prompt user for markup percentage
InputPercentage = Application.InputBox("What deposit percentage would you like to charge?", "Enter a number", , , , , , Type:=1)

'prompt user for date to be displayed on estimate
EstimateDate = Application.InputBox("What date would you like on the estimate document?  Please enter as MM/DD/YYYY.", "Date")

WorkingPercentage = InputPercentage / 100

'prompt user whether or not to include subcategory totals
subcat_yn = MsgBox("Would you like to include subtotals next to labor subcategories in the estimate?", vbYesNo, "Display labor subcategory subtotals?")

If subcat_yn = vbYes Then
  subcatprice = "y"
ElseIf subcat_yn = vbNo Then
  subcatprice = "n"
End If

'clear out estimate sheet
est_sht.Cells.Clear

'remove gridlines
est_sht.Activate
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

'set fill color of cells FIND CORRECT COLOR CODE
'With est_sht.Cells.Interior
'        .Pattern = xlSolid
'        .PatternColorIndex = -4142
'        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
'        .TintAndShade = 0
'        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
'    End With

'set row height of top accent bar
est_sht.Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 10

'set width of left 2 columns
est_sht.Columns("A:A").columnwidth = 1
est_sht.Columns("B:B").columnwidth = 3

'set color of top accent bar
With est_sht.Range("A1:J1").Interior
.Color = vbBlack
End With

'set row 2 height
est_sht.Rows("2:2").RowHeight = 16.5

'set row 3 height
est_sht.Rows("3:3").RowHeight = 80

'set text formatting
With est_sht.Rows("3:3").Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 15
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0.349986266670736
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
est_sht.Rows("3:3").Font.Bold = True

'Date stamp the estimate based on form input
est_sht.Cells(3, 3).Value = EstimateDate

'title the estimate
est_sht.Cells(3, 5).Value = "Cost Estimate"

'Insert header row text'
est_sht.Cells(4, 3).Value = "PROJECT TASKS"
est_sht.Cells(4, 4).Value = "Cost Estimate"
est_sht.Cells(4, 5).FormulaR1C1 = InputPercentage & "% Deposit"
est_sht.Cells(4, 6).Value = "Current Costs"

'format header row
With est_sht.Rows("4:4")
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
With est_sht.Rows("4:4").Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 9
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0.349986266670736
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With

est_sht.Rows("4:4").Font.Bold = True

'create variant array of worksheets
WshtNames = Array("permits", "project management", "in progress design", "site prep", "services on site", "layout", "concrete", "water management", "framing", "roofing and sheet metal", "electrical", "plumbing", "HVAC", "windows and doors", "exterior finishes", "insulation", "drywall", "painting", "cabinetry", "countertops", "interior finishes", "flooring", "tile", "deck garden", "landscaping", "appliances", "punchlist", "add-ons", "contingency")

'loop through worksheets
  For WshtNameCrnt = LBound(WshtNames) To UBound(WshtNames)
     With Worksheets(WshtNames(WshtNameCrnt))

        'find last row on estimate page
        With est_sht
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                EstLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=.Range("B1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
            Else
                EstLastRow = 1
            End If
        End With

        'format sub-header
        est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 6)).Font.Bold = True
        est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 6)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 6)).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0.349986266670736
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
        End With

        'Find last row on current worksheet
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
            Else
                LastRow = 1
            End If

        'count the number of rows filled with sub-categories'
        NumRows = LastRow - 4

        'pull sub-categories from current worksheet tab to estimate page
        est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 3), est_sht.Cells(NumRows + EstLastRow + 3, 3)).Value = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).Value

        'add sheet name to table
        est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3).Value = .Name

        'add sequential numbers next to labor categories on estimate page
        'handle the case of a single subcategory
        If NumRows = 1 Then
            est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2).Value = 1
        ElseIf NumRows > 1 Then
            est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2).Value = 1
            est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 4, 2), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
        End If

        'set black fill color in sequential numbers sidebar
        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 2), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 2)).Interior
        .Color = vbBlack
        End With
        'format text of sequential numbers
        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 2)).Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 9
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        'format sequential numbers bold
        est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 2)).Font.Bold = True

        'copy cost subtotal to estimate page
        est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 4).Value = .Range("G1").Value

        'initiate do while loop for labor subcategory subtotals
        Do
            'pull subtotals from subcategory items to estimate
            est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 4), est_sht.Cells(NumRows + EstLastRow + 3, 4)).Value = .Range(.Cells(4, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7)).Value
            'set formula for deposit numbers on estimate sheet
            'populate deposit formula in estimate page
            est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 5), est_sht.Cells(NumRows + EstLastRow + 3, 5)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*" & WorkingPercentage
            'populate sum formula in "current costs" for labor category
            'set formula for totals on estimate sheet
            est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 6), est_sht.Cells(NumRows + EstLastRow + 3, 6)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]:RC[-1])"
            'set text formatting of subtotals, deposits, and totals
            est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 4), est_sht.Cells(NumRows + EstLastRow + 3, 6)).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
            With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 4), est_sht.Cells(NumRows + EstLastRow + 3, 6)).Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 9
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0.349986266670736
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
            End With
        Loop While subcat_yn = y And Not subcat_yn = n

        'populate deposit formula in estimate page
        est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*" & WorkingPercentage
        'populate sum formula in "current costs" for labor category
        est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]:RC[-1])"

        'format sub-category items text
        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 9
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0.349986266670736
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
        End With

        'format table around sub-category items and costs
        est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 2, 3), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 6)).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

        'repaint screen as macro works and scroll with the active line
        est_sht.Activate
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = EstLastRow

      End With
  Next WshtNameCrnt

'this else statement refers to the msgbox statement that initializes the macro
Else
    Exit Sub
'end of main if/else loop, and end of sub'
End If

'set typeface for entire estimate sheet
est_sht.Cells.Font.Name = "Arial"

'autofit columns in entire estimate sheet
est_sht.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'remove row column under header
est_sht.Rows("5:5").Delete Shift:=xlUp

est_sht.Activate

End Sub
```

Here is my current code for the numbering:

```
If NumRows = 1 Then
    est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2).Value = 1

ElseIf NumRows > 1 Then
    est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2).Value = 1
    est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 4, 2), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"

End If
```

This works fine for tables that have three or more items, but tables with 1 item have no numbers, and tables with 2 items only have the first item numbered, with no numeric value next to the second item.  Here's an example of the output I'm getting:

[image: example sequential numbering output]

I've tried a couple other approaches, including using an ElseIf statement for a 2 item list:

```
If NumRows = 1 Then
    est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2).Value = 1

ElseIf NumRows = 2 Then
    est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2).Value = 1
    est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 4, 2).Value = 2

ElseIf NumRows > 2 Then
    est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 3, 2).Value = 1
    est_sht.Range(est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + 4, 2), est_sht.Cells(EstLastRow + NumRows + 3, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"

End If
```

But that results in the same problem.

Comment: Is the data in Excel tables? What is the name of the column you are putting the formula in? .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"   And do you just want each table to have a column that has the number 1,2,3 etc in a column under the header?

Comment: Did the code below work for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

**Version for numbering lists in a sheet**:

with the following main assumptions:

1) Start row of numbering range is `B6`

2) Header sections are always in Bold e.g. **Dry Wall**

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddRowNumsToListItems()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim est_sht As Worksheet
    Dim numRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long                          'lastRow in col C
    Dim currRow As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set est_sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")        'change as appropriate

    lastRow = est_sht.Cells(est_sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set numRange = est_sht.Range("C5:C" & lastRow)

    Dim counter As Long

    counter = 0

    For Each currRow In numRange.Rows            'loop column C

        If Not currRow.Font.Bold And Not IsEmpty(currRow) Then
            counter = counter + 1
            currRow.Offset(, -1) = counter 'adjacent column add number
        Else
           counter = 0
        End If

    Next currRow

End Sub
```

**Excel table version**:

With the following assumptions:

1. Data is set up as Excel tables and you have a column called RowNum in each table that holds the sequential row numbering for the table
2. Row numbering starts at one for each table
3. Every table in `est_sht` will have this numbering added

In essence, there is a Function `ListTables` which collects all the table names in the sheet `est_sht` and stores them in an array `tableArr`.

There is a procedure `AddRowNumsToTables` that calls this function and loops the table names adding an active cell formula `"=ROW()-ROW(" & tableArr(currTable) & ")+1"` to the column `RowNum` which sequentially numbers the rows in each table.

Let me know if this is close to what you were after.

In a standard module put the following:

```
Private Sub AddRowNumsToTables()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim est_sht As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set est_sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim tableArr() As String

    tableArr = ListTables

    Dim currTable As Long

    For currTable = LBound(tableArr) To UBound(tableArr)

        With est_sht.ListObjects(tableArr(currTable))

            est_sht.Range(tableArr(currTable) & "[RowNum]").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()-ROW(" & tableArr(currTable) & ")+1"

        End With

    Next currTable
End Sub

Private Function ListTables() As String()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim est_sht As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tableArr() As String
    ReDim tableArr(0 To 100)
    Dim counter As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set est_sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    counter = 0

    For Each tbl In est_sht.ListObjects
        tableArr(counter) = tbl.Name
        counter = counter + 1
    Next tbl

    ReDim Preserve tableArr(0 To counter - 1)

    ListTables = tableArr

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Your answer has made me realize that I was perhaps using the term "table" a little too liberally.  I was not aware that there was an existing function in VBA for creating tables, so I was essentially building them from scratch by formatting relative cell areas in the estimate sheet.  I have updated my original question with the full macro code as well as some sample output.  I may end up entirely rewriting it to incorporate your suggestion, but am interested in your take on what I have already coded.

Comment: The problem should still  be easy to solve. Questions: The numbering is going in column B? Is there anything else other than the items you want numbered  (and their category headers) in column C? Are headers e.g. drywall always in bold?  Is there a fixed start row in B e.g. where DryWall would be placed if it was the first thing in your lists on the sheet. And how are you determining the value of EstLastRow? I can't see that in the code.

Comment: Yes, the numbering is in column b, nothing other than what you mentioned will go in column c, and headers are always bold.  The fixed row where the first bold heading would always start is 5.

Comment: EstLastRow:`With est_sht
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                    EstLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=.Range("B1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
                Else
                    EstLastRow = 1
                End If
            End With`

Comment: Have edited answer with new sub (version for lists) that gives you logic for numbering column B dependant on what is in column C. Changes worksheet names as appropriate. Assumes your data is already in column C.